# How to get current market price of a list of stocks with nsetools?

Tags: python, csv, stock

I am trying to write a simple program which uses a list of stocks in a csv. I am using library called `nsetools` which provides stock info for the Indian stock market.
Loop should pick stock code from the csv and print current market price of stock.
However, I am getting the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anoopmah/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 15, in <module>
    p = nse.get_quote('temp')['lastPrice']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Code:

```
import nsetools
import pandas as pd
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()

#Import CSV into dataframe
filepath = "C:/temp/Stock/stocklist.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding='windows-1252')

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    temp = df["Name"][i]
    print(temp)
    p = nse.get_quote('temp')['lastPrice']
    print(p)
```

Comment: Make sure to click the green checkmark next to an answer if it is valid, and try to directly ask a question for people to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error states that you tried to subscript (use `[]`) an object which does not have the functionality to do so. In this case, it is saying that an object with the value `None` (hence, `... 'NoneType' object ...`) was attempted to be subscripted.

If we check the line where the error occurred, you see the following line of code:

```py
p = nse.get_quote('temp')['lastPrice']
```

What is happening here is that you are trying to retrieve the data from the quote 'temp', then get the value which matches the key (in the data dictionary) 'lastPrice'. The problem with this is that presumably, the function `get_quote` is returning `None`. As you can see, in the [documentation](https://nsetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=None#checking-if-the-code-is-valid) it is specified that *"In case you perform a get_quote or get_index_quote on a code which is invalid, then the APIs return None. It doesn’t raise exception as one might expect."*

Therefore, you can conclude that the bug is happening due to 'temp' being an invalid quote.

Comment: Thanks Xiddoc. However, I found a way to get last Price of multiple quotes by stocks = ['INDUSINDBK', 'SHREECEM','SBIN','NATIONALUM']
data = {stock:nse.get_quote(stock)['lastPrice'] for stock in stocks}
print(data)